# Toolbar: Hamburger button not center vertically on Android 6

Tags: android, android-toolbar

here my activity's layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">    
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mainActivityFrameLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>       
            </LinearLayout>    
        </LinearLayout>            
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/widgetRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/windowBackground"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here tool_bar's layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolBarConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tool_bar_height"
        android:background="@color/place_holder_color"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbaTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test title center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolBar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolBar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here result on Andorid 6.0:

[image: toolbar]

As you can see the hamburger button is not center vertically.

Here result on Android 4.3. All is show correct:

[image: toolbar_2]

Why on **Android 4.3**, the hamburger button correct show, but on **Android 6.0** not correct?

Comment: This really looks to me like your `Toolbar` is getting extra padding, as though it had `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` set, though of course I don't see that attr in the code you posted.

Comment: fitsSystemWindows - not help